# NoClassDefFoundError exception in war file

Tags: java, war, noclassdeffounderror, web-inf

I have jar files in WEB-INF/lib folder of the war file. When I run the server on Android (I'm using i-jetty as a web server), I get NoClassDefFoundError exception. The class that gives error is in one of the jar files. Software could not reach the class files in the jar file at runtime. What should I do? I produced classes.dex file by using WEB-INF/classes folder and put this classes.zip file in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

> `NoClassDefFoundError` exception. The class that gives error is in one of the jar files. Software could not reach the class files in the jar file at runtime

That's not what it means. `NoClassDefFoundError` usually means you have a .class file in the wrong place, i.e. not containing the class or package that its name position in the file system suggests.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I suggest you check what's in the file for the class named in the exception.